# Issue with template struct in struct -

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
struct _sApplicationPoolHeader
{
    int iApplicationList;
    T* oData;
};

template <class T>
struct _sAppPoolNode
{
    _sAppPoolNode* psNext;
    _sApplicationPoolHeader<T> psHeader;

    _sAppPoolNode()
    {
        psNext = NULL;
    }
};
```

Why I got a complilation error while I declare this:
p.s:
If I declare template above the class, its work.

```
class ApplicationPoolMng
{
private:
    template <class T>
    _sAppPoolNode<T>  m_psAppPool;
}

error: data member 'm_psAppPool' cannot be a member template _sAppPoolNode<T>  m_psAppPool;
```

Comment: Let's imagine it was possible. What memory layout will an `ApplicationPoolMng` object have?

Comment: And as a side note, if those classes are in global scope, you ask for trouble naming them with a leading underscore. Global scope identifiers that begin with an underscore, are reserved by the C++ implementation itself.

Comment: If you declare a (non-templated) class ApplicationPoolMng then the compiler needs to know the size of the class. But he does not know the size of members that are templates. Of course you can have a member with like _sAppPoolNode<int> where the template is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax can only be used to define function member templates.
Use instead:

```
template <class T>
class ApplicationPoolMng
{
private:
    _sAppPoolNode<T>  m_psAppPool;
};
```

All the class needs to be templated, not just the member.